# pandas DataFrame automatically reordering my columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm not sure if this is an update in python or some random bug, but it only recently started happening for me.  I am defining a pandas DataFrame in python.  I'm explicitly defining the columns and column order using something like:

df = pandas.DataFrame(
                      {
                       'col1': column-1 data,
                       'col2': column-2 data,
                       etc...
                       }
                      )

However, when I print, or directly export the DataFrame 'df', python is reordering my columns to be:

[ [Index, 0, 1, 2, etc], [col-2, 0, 1, 2, etc], [col-1, 0, 1, 2, etc] ], when it should be

[ [Index, 0, 1, 2, etc], [col-1, 0, 1, 2, etc], [col-2, 0, 1, 2, etc] ].

I'm attaching some randomly generated data that highlights this issue.  I've tried everything from redoing all arrays using numpy, pd.Series, but nothing is correcting this issue when I collect all the arrays into one pd.DataFrame.

Any tips or thoughts on what could be causing this column reordering in pandas?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#Independent Variable Definition
x   =   np.linspace( -10, 10, num = 201, endpoint = True)


#Dependent Variable - 1 Definition
binary_data     =   pd.DataFrame(
                                 {
                                  'random': np.random.randint( 2, size = 201 )
                                  }
                                 )

binary_data['sorted']   =   pd.DataFrame(
                                         binary_data.sort_values(['random'])
                                         ).reset_index(drop = True)

binary_data['sorted_w_noise']   =   binary_data['sorted']
binary_data['sorted_w_noise'][3::4] = 0
binary_data['sorted_w_noise'][4::5] = 1
binary_data['sorted_w_noise'][5::6] = 0
binary_data['sorted_w_noise'][6::7] = 1


#Dependent Variable - 2 Definition
y   =   (1/3)*x + 1

noise   =   np.array( np.random.normal( 0, 0.15, 201 ) )

linear_data     =   np.array( y + noise )


#Create pandas DataFrames for purposes of exporting to .xlsx or .csv
logit_data  =   pd.DataFrame(
                             {
                              'ind_var': x,
                              'dep_var': binary_data['sorted_w_noise']
                              }
                             )

lin_data    =   pd.DataFrame(
                             {
                              'ind_var': x,
                              'dep_var': linear_data
                              }
                             )
```

Comment: you're passing a dict as the data, the keys by design do not maintain creation order, you'd need to specify the column order in the `columns` arg in the dataframe ctor, I'll find the dupe

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254287/why-does-the-pandas-the-dataframe-column-order-change-automatically